# deploying Xamarin forms application to android phone

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am very new to xamarin forms. I developed a simple autocomplete application in Xamrin forms using Visual studio 2017 enterprise version. I want to deploy that application to android phones. When I created the application, I selected Cross Platform app (xamarin.forms or Native). below is the image of visual studio run button:

[image]

and the properties of the project are below:

[image]

any article or any steps to deploy this application to android phones will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/debug-on-device/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Set Up Device for Development - source** - https://developer.xamarin.com](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/)

- [Enable Debugging on the Device](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/#Enable_Debugging_on_the_Device) - By default, it will not be possible to debug applications on a Android device.
- [Install USB Drivers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/#Install_USB_Drivers) - This step is not necessary for OS X computers. Windows computers may require the installation of USB drivers.
- [Connect the Device to the Computer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/#Connect_the_Device_to_the_Computer) - The final step involves connecting the device to the computer by either USB or WiFi.

Once a device is connected to your computer you will see your device like this

[image]

Now Click the green arrow to start deploy and debug.

additional - This link will show you how to debug and prepare APK for release
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/